# JUnitで、モック化したインスタンスの中のprivate fieldの内容を検証したい

Tags: java, junit

いつもお世話になっております。
掲題についてご相談させてください。
以下のようなソースコードがあったとします。

試験対象のコード

```
public class テスト対象のクラス{
　　@Inject
    private モック化したいクラス セッション;
　　　　
    public boolean テスト対象のメソッド(){
         // ...適当な処理...
         セッション.getMap().put("テストKey", "テストValue");
         // ...適当な処理...
         return true;
    }
}

public class モック化したいクラス{
    private Map<String, String> 試験対象のマップ;
    public Map<String, String> getMap(){
        return 試験対象のマップ;
    }
}
```

テストの実行コード

```
//...
import org.mockito.Mock; // テスト用ライブラリとしてMockitoを使用
//...
public class テスト対象のクラスTest{

    /**
     * テスト対象のクラス
     */
    @Inject
    @InjectMocks
    テスト対象のクラス service;

    // モック用
    モック化したいクラス モックインスタンス = mock(モック化したいクラス.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // モックを有効にする
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void テスト() {
        // 戻り値のテストはOK
        assertThat(test, is(service.テスト対象のメソッド()));

　　    // モックを呼び出した時に、
        // 試験対象のマップの検証はどうすればよいでしょうか。
       // verify()?
       // argumentcaptor?
    }

}
```

上記処理の通り、途中でセッションにつめた変数の内容を検証したいのですが、
何かいい方法はないでしょうか。

皆様のお知恵をお借りできれば幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`モック化したいクラス#getMap()`メソッドで返されるインスタンスを検証できるように、自前で用意した(=テストコード側で用意した)インスタンスを返すようにすれば良いです。
Mockitoでは次のように書けます([ドキュメント](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing))。

```
when(モックインスタンス.getMap()).thenReturn(map);
```

テストコード全体としては、次のようになります:

```
public class テスト対象のクラスTest {

    @Inject
    @InjectMocks
    テスト対象のクラス service;

    @Mock
    private モック化したいクラス モックインスタンス;

    private Map<String, String> map;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        when(モックインスタンス.getMap()).thenReturn(map);
    }

    @Test
    public void テスト() {
        assertThat(true, is(service.テスト対象のメソッド()));

        assertEquals(1, map.keySet().size());
        assertEquals("テストKey", map.keySet().iterator().next());
        assertEquals("テストValue", map.values().iterator().next());
    }
}
```